# take photo with camera or choose from gallery popover using phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am working with the phonegap camera plugin.

I was wondering if there's an option or a way to have the "choose from camera or photoalbum" dialog pop over appear instead of strictly just the photo album or camera option that's currently available.

```
        navigator.camera.getPicture(gotPic, onFail, {
            quality: 10,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300
        });
```

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this from documentation

html

```
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>

<button onclick="getPhoto();">From Photo Library</button>
```

js

```
  pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
  destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;

  function capturePhoto() {

   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
  }

function getPhoto() {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY});
}
```

now you can use these buttons on a dialog or popup to provide user with two different options

P>S : dont forget to give success and fail callback functions

Comment: I see so, the idea is to manually add in a popover or dialog to then give them the option.  Thanks, will give this a shot.

Comment: sure you can add this buttons in it (Y) giving user both options is indeed requirement :)